# Visibility "animation" but a delay on the reverse effect in SCSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I'm creating an element that I want to hide initially, but when a class is added, it will appear and animate the top. The issue with this, is that on class remove, the visibility is triggered instantly, then top is animated. How do I make sure, in SCSS, that the on class remove, visibility isn't effected until after the top animation?

```js
$(window).on("load", function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $(".nav-slider").toggleClass("is_visible");
  });
});
```

```css
.nav-slider {
  position:fixed;
  top:-100%;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:calc(100% - 60px);
  background-color:$white;
  z-index:1;
  visibility:hidden;
  transition:top 0.2s, visibility 0s;
  -o-transition:top 0.2s, visibility 0s;
  -ms-transition:top 0.2s, visibility 0s;
  -moz-transition:top 0.2s, visibility 0s;
  -webkit-transition:top 0.2s, visibility 0s;
  padding-top:40px;
}

.nav-slider.is_visible {
  top:60px;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav-slider">
test
</div>

<button>slider</button>
```

Comment: In that case you don't even need the visibility property or the additional transition as provided below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have a different transition for `.is_visible`

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(".nav-slider").toggleClass("is_visible");
  });
});
```

```css
.nav-slider {
  position: fixed;
  top: -100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  background-color: $white;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding-top: 40px;
  transition: top 2s, visibility 2s;
}

.nav-slider.is_visible {
  transition: top 2s, visibility 0s;
  top: 60px;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-slider">
  test
</div>

<button>slider</button>
```